# Unable to Display Check Mark in Particular row in TableView and want to set a checkmark in a UITableView first time the table is loaded with data?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to coding, I have a mutable array that contains nearly 20 names and I loaded that in a table view. I want to show checkmark for a particular name row in table view based on ID but am unable to do that. Please help to fix that issue.

Here I give the code what I am tried.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView == productListTableView {
        let cell:BillTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BillTableViewCell") as! BillTableViewCell
        let productName:String = (productNameArray[indexPath.row] as? String)!
        cell.productNameLbl.text = productName

        print("addIdsMutArray :",addIdsMutArray)
        print(addIdsMutArray.count)
        print("oldSelectedIDStr :",oldSelectedIDStr)

        for i in (0..<addIdsMutArray.count)
        {   var arrayCheck = NSArray()
            arrayCheck = addIdsMutArray[i] as! NSArray
            print(self.addIdsMutArray)

            if arrayCheck.contains(oldSelectedIDStr)
            {
                print("Found")
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
                tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.bottom)
            } else {
                print("Not Found")
                cell.accessoryType = .none
            }
        }return cell}
```

Comment: Do not call `tableView.selectRow` in `cellForRowAt`. The only thing you should in `cellForRowAt` is setup and return one cell.

Comment: And why do you have the `for` loop? Just determine if the current `indexPath` should be checked or not.

Comment: because the mutable array has sub-arrays so only I checked with for loop.

Comment: And I want to set a checkmark in a UITableView first time the table is loaded with data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the loop, here the solution:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView == productListTableView {
        let cell:BillTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BillTableViewCell") as! BillTableViewCell
        let productName:String = (productNameArray[indexPath.row] as? String)!
        cell.productNameLbl.text = productName

        print("addIdsMutArray :",addIdsMutArray)
        print(addIdsMutArray.count)
        print("oldSelectedIDStr :",oldSelectedIDStr)
        //set not check for default
        cell.accessoryType = .none
        for i in (0..<addIdsMutArray.count)
        {   var arrayCheck = NSArray()
            arrayCheck = addIdsMutArray[i] as! NSArray
            print(self.addIdsMutArray)

            if arrayCheck.contains(oldSelectedIDStr)
            {
                print("Found")
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
                tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.bottom) 
                break;
            } 
        }
        return cell
}
```

Comment: 1. Do not use `NSArray` with Swift. 2. Why assign a value to `arrayCheck` and then on the next line assign another new value? 3. Do not call `selectRow` inside `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: @rmaddy I know, I only copy and paste his code and fix it :)

Comment: You only fixed one of several issues. A really good answer would offer advice on how to improve the rest of the code.

Comment: This code displays the checkmark in all the rows but I need to display in particular row which the name is based on ID, I want to set a checkmark in a UITableView first time the table is loaded with data.@JosePoseS

Comment: @saravanaKumarB this code only checkmark row with id is on list, no all rows  `//set not check for default cell.accessoryType = .none` default not checked, maybe you must remove `tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.bottom)`, maybe the problem is the oldSelectedIDStr ... because you always use the same addIdsMutArray, not different array on different row... like `productNameArray[indexPath.row]`

Answer (score -2):

Consider this generic code that shows checkmark in every alternate cell. Edit the if condition to match yours.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0{
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }else{
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }
    cell.textLabel?.text = dummyData[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

This is how it looks:

[image: This is how it looks:]

The only difference is the lack of your call to selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.bottom).
I'm not sure why this is done, but understand that at the end of the loop only the last matched cell will be selected.

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been downvoted. If it's because the code is generic, I expect the asker to fill in his specifics. If you feel it wont work, I've attached a screenshot. If it's anything else, please help me improve my answer.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted it, but maybe it was because you didn't answer the question? The OP ***already*** is using `cell.accessoryType = .checkmark` and `cell.accessoryType = .none`.

Comment: Okay. I'll highlight the difference :)

Comment: Thanks for your help but this code not working.@7to4